# Removing everything up to and including the last "/" from variable value

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am currently learning how to use `grep` `awk` `sed`. I am encountering an issue with a variable that has the value of the following: `new_file="main_folder/test.txt"`. Practically a directory with a file inside. I am able to initially use sed to remove the file extension. But the main goal is to just get the file name `test`(no extension)  extracted from the variable `new_file`. How could I remove everything to the last and the file extension?

So far all that i have working is removing extension

```
new_file=`rev <<< "$new_file" | cut -d"." -f2- | rev`
```

Example:

*Input*

```
new_file="parent_folder/child_folder/file_name.txt"
new_file2="parent_folder/child_folder/sub_child_folder/file_name2.txt"
```

*Desired Output:*

```
file_name
file_name2
```

Comment: Regexps are your friends. Try matching any character followed by a '/'. This would match all the dir/ subdir/ parts which can then be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `basename` utility.

```
$ new_file="parent_folder/child_folder/file_name.txt"
$ x=$(basename "$new_file" .txt)
$ echo "$x"
file_name
```

or your case

```
new_file=`basename $new_file | cut -d "." --complement -f2-`
```

Comment: how could I assign the value of `basename $new_file` to another variable?

Comment: True, `basename` can only strip the extension if you know the exact extension.

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ new_file="parent_folder/child_folder/file_name.txt"
$ new_file2="parent_folder/child_folder/sub_child_folder/file_name2.txt"
$ sed 's~.*/\([^/.]*\)\..*$~\1~' <<< "$new_file"
file_name
$ sed 's~.*/\([^/.]*\)\..*$~\1~' <<< "$new_file2"
file_name2
```

To assign the value to another variable,

```
$ foo=$(sed 's~.*/\([^/.]*\)\..*$~\1~' <<< "$new_file2")
$ echo "$foo"
file_name2
```

Simply you could try this sed command.

```
$ sed 's~.*/\(.*\)\..*$~\1~' <<< "$new_file2"
file_name2
```